# Unable to increase disk size of sda1 in virtual machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, partitioning, gparted

I have a linux virtual machine configured in windows host using Virtualbox. The virtual machine has got 15 GB storage with one primary partition (sda1) and an extended partition. My primary partition is almost used up and I would like to expand the capacity by another 4 GB. Using Gparted Live I could shrink the extended partition to salvage about 4 GB space. However, I am unable to increase the size of primary partition using this newly created space. How can this be achieved?
The screenshot below depict the situation that I am facing.

[Paritions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3kmP.jpg)

[Incresing size of primary partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl0M1.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It's a very old topic. You need first to move the unallocated space outside the extended partition, see [here](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dmoving-space-between-partitions), then you need to resize the primary partition, see [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_resizing_ext3_partitions_p2).

In the second reference, an *ext3* partition is resized, it makes no difference for an *ext4* partition, just substitute *ext4* wherever *ext3* appears. Also notice the following: this **cannot** be achieved from within *gparted*, because you are trying to alter the exact partition (*/dev/sda1*) on which the Linux operating system resides, which is a big no-no. After freeing the unallocated space from the extended partition, you will have to shut down the VM, insert the installation disk and **boot from this**, not from your (virtual) HDD. Then you use the OS on the installation disk to enlarge (without data loss) the */dev/sda1* partition from *outside* your system, so to speak. This is what the instructions achieve with a Knoppix disk, which you do not need because you should still have the installation disk. That's all.